# Are a function's endpoints always at a higher address than it's entry point?

Tags: memory-address, decompiling

The title may seem confusing, but let me explain.

I'm doing static binary analysis and I am trying to get paths from a function entry point to it's endpoint (understand: start address of a basic block that returns).

However, I sometimes have cases where an endpoint is located in another function, and I would like to remove some of these false positives by simply constraining endpoints to basic blocks which addresses are higher than the function entry point (this would at least remove blocks whose functions have been declared earlier, which would represent most of the cases in a linux kernel module).

So my question is, since I can't really determine that by just trying, **can I consider that every function's endpoint is located AFTER the entry point ?**

This would make sense to me, but I'd prefer to be sure that there aren't any nasty case.

EDIT: 
My use case is Linux kernel modules (so mostly x86 ELFs right now)

Thank you

Comment: I don't know enough about this to hazard an answer, but I would be surprised if the answer was as language/compiler/OS/architecture - independent as your question suggests.

Comment: I will try to restrict the question to my use case then, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: How is it that those false positives in other functions are coming up in your analysis?  Every CPU I've read up on by default loads the next instruction from the next address, so the endpoint coming after the entry point should be the common case, but is not generally required by the instruction set so I wouldn't assume it's universal.

Comment: I am using `angr` which has an option to give me endpoints, and sometimes, when my function calls another function before returning, they appear.

Comment: Can you share an example of that output?  If you're doing static analysis, I wouldn't expect endpoints of called functions to get inserted.